# Where to place the mysqli_close when the function returns a value?

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

I'm curious about what the mysqli_close actually does and when it should be called. I have this dB class where other classes can call the public methods to execute queries. However I'm not really sure where and if I should place the mysqli_close connection.

1. Is the data still present in the return variable when I closed the connection after the return $row, this method will be called many times from other classes.
2. When the function is called from another class does it then still have the data when the connection is closed. Or does it then not exist anymore despite it was stored in a variable which was returned to the class who called the function.
3. Is it possible to even call the mysqli_close connection after the return value ? Or is the method stopped because it returned a value and because of that will never call the mysqli_close function ?
4. Because it's an old framework written by somebody else I don't have a base class which all classes are extend from so I don't have any easy way of closing the connection at the end of each php file. If I wan't to do that I will need to add mysqli_close in like 500+ files. Which I think is the wrong approach.
5. Any idea's about how to solve this problem would be appreciated !

For example I have this function:

```
function getRecord($sql) {
    if ($this->connect()) {
        if ($result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql)) {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                return $row;
                // mysqli_close($this->connection);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // mysqli_close($this->connection);
}
```

Comment: __No__ code after `return` is executed.

Comment: And you should look into magic method `__destruct` and place all any resource closing code there

Comment: Most code doesn't explicitly close connections (they are automatically closed after the connection is no longer used), a more common pattern would be to open a connection early on in the script and then re-use the same connection all through.

Comment: Nobody has any business using `mysqli_close` and similar functions. If there was a connection pool depletion, business logic would usually be the wrong place to fix it.

Comment: @mario that's absolutely correct. However I don't want to spend hours and hours fixing this issue on something that will not be running for a long time anymore so for now I'm in for the quick fix. Because it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks, as expected, just confirming.

Comment: @kellymandem thanks this was the hint I was looking for ... feeling a bit stupid, I didn't think of this. Thanks all.